# hiding appbar on overlay progress bar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working a windows phone 7 application.Now in this application on specific user input i show overlay progress bar from coding4fun Silverlight toolkit.

But App bar on that page on which i am showing overlay progress bar remains active.

I want to make it generic that when ever I call overlay

progress bar.show()

App bar should be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BindableApplicationBar from the Phone7Fx library here :-

http://phone7.codeplex.com/

You can then bind the IsVisible property of the BindableApplicationBar to the Visibility property of the ProgressOverlay, using XAML as follows :-

```
<phone7fx:BindableApplicationBar x:Name="AppBar"
                                     BarOpacity="1"
                                     IsVisible="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=MyProgressOverlay, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBooleanConverter}}" />
```

Then if you call the Show or Hide method against the ProgressOverlay then the Application Bar will Appear and Disappear accordingly.

Bear in mind that you define the Phone7.Fx BindableApplicationBar within the last Grid tag and not before the last phone:PhoneApplicationPage.